# FullCalendar - eventMouseover and eventMouseout Events are not working on custom view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, dom-events, custom-view

I developed a calendar with `FullCalendar` and I use the standard-view and a custom view which displays my events in a list-like-style.

Everything is shown up properly but the default `eventMouseover` and `eventMouseout-handler` are not called for events on my custom view.

Is there any special requirements I have to do in the `renderEvents-Function`? The only thing I do there is to build the event-table html.

Or do I miss some options? I haven't found a solution yet.

This is my fullCalendar-initialisation:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      validRange: {
        start: '2018-01-01',
        end: '2025-12-31'
      },
      navLinks: true,
      header : {
          left: 'month,custom,listYear, today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'prev,next'
      },
    views: {
        month: {
            buttonText: monthTitle,
            duration: { month: 1 }
        },
        listYear: {
            buttonText: "LIST-YEAR",
            visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
                var myStart = (currentDate.get("year")-1) + "-12-31";
                var myEnd   = (currentDate.get("year")) + "-12-31";
                return {
                    start: myStart,
                    end: myEnd
                };
            },
            duration: { year: 1 }
        },
        custom: {
            buttonText: yearTitle,
            visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
                var myStart = (currentDate.get("year")-1) + "-12-31";
                var myEnd   = (currentDate.get("year")) + "-12-31";
                return {
                    start: myStart,
                    end: myEnd
                };
            },
            duration: { year: 1 }
        }
      },
      viewRender: function(view,element) {
        if(view.name=="month"){
          //month
          $('.fc-today-button').show();
        }else {
          //listYear
          $('.fc-today-button').hide();
        }
      },
      eventOrder: sortEvents,
      defaultView: defView,
      columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd',
      weekNumberTitle: kwTitle,
      weekNumbers: true,
      contentHeight: calHeight,
      aspectRatio: 2,
      locale: curLocale, 
      defaultDate: startDate,
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: false ,
      events:  './calAction.php?do=getEvents',
      eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          var objId = ".ev" + calEvent.id;
          if(calEvent.type == 0) {
              objId = ".hd" + calEvent.id;
          }
          if( !$(objId).hasClass("tooltipstered")) {
              var ttHtml = calEvent.tt;
                $(objId).tooltipster({
                   animation: 'fade',
                   delay: 200,
                   contentAsHTML: true,
                   content: ttHtml
                });
          }
          $(objId).tooltipster('open');
      },
      eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          var objId = ".ev" + calEvent.id;
          if(calEvent.type == 0) {
              objId = ".hd" + calEvent.id;
          }

          if($(objId).hasClass("tooltipstered")) {
              $(objId).tooltipster('close');
          }              
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          jsEvent.stopPropagation();

          if(curActiveEventObj != null ) {
            curActiveEventObj.removeClass("evActive");
          }
          var editable = calEvent.editable;
          if( editable ) {
            $(this).addClass("evActive");
            curActiveEventObj = $(this);
            curActiveEvent = calEvent;
          }
          else {
              curActiveEventObj = null;
              curActiveEvent = null;
          }
      },
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
          if(curActiveEventObj != null ) {
              curActiveEventObj.removeClass("evActive");
              curActiveEventObj = null;
          }

          ignoreFirstClick = true;
          var dateObj = date.toDate();

          if( dateObj < new Date() ) {
              return;
          }
          $("#eTitle").val('');
          $("#eDesc").html('');
          $("#eStart").data('DateTimePicker').date(dateObj);
          $("#eEnd").data('DateTimePicker').date(dateObj);


          $("#inputDlg").fadeIn("fast", function() {
          });
      },
      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
          var evId = event.id;
          var days = delta.days();
          curUpdateEventId  = evId;
          curUpdateRevertFunc = revertFunc;

          updateEventDate(event, evId, days);
      },
      eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
          var evId = event.id;
          var days = delta.days();
          curUpdateEventId  = evId;
          curUpdateRevertFunc = revertFunc;

          updateEventSpan(event, evId, days);
      }          
    });
```

Ok, I guess I found the source in fullcalendar.js which seems to bind the html-elements of an event to the mouseover/out handlers .. Must do more research on how to implement ...

```
var EventPointing = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
tslib_1.__extends(EventPointing, _super);
function EventPointing() {
    return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
}
/*
component must implement:
  - publiclyTrigger
*/
EventPointing.prototype.bindToEl = function (el) {
    var component = this.component;
    component.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
    component.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'mouseenter', 
    this.handleMouseover.bind(this));
    component.bindSegHandlerToEl(el, 'mouseleave', 
this.handleMouseout.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please edit  your question and add your calendar initialization code.

Comment: I guess I have to 'connect' the calendar-event somehow with the html-element to activate the mouse-.events for the calendar events ?!

Comment: So if the eventMouseover and eventMouseout are the only two event handlers that aren't working, I suspect your `$(objId)` logic isn't working like you think it does. Add some console logs to these functions to see if 1) `objId ` is being built correctly, and 2) if the `$(objId)` selector is finding any elements.

Comment: No thats not the point. The handlers aren't even called. In the default views the handlers are called for every event. Just on my custom view (with the same events) the handlers aren't called. It must be something like registering the events for the handler or so .. I didn't got it yet ..

Comment: How do you know these handlers aren't being called?

Comment: By using breakpoints..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution out of the standard-way of handling the user-events.

I organize the events in the custom view by myself and wrote own mouse-handlers for the custom view.

Everey works as expected but it is somehow sad that the documentation doen't cover up this tasks ..

Comment: It would be great if you could write the code that worked for you. I'm also having the same issue where `eventClick` function is not getting called inside a custom view.